# Solving Equation of Motion during Preheating in Mixed-$R^2$

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, curvature, cosmological-inflation

Recently, I have an interest in Mixed Higgs-$R^2$ inflation and its preheating. However, there are some problems that I faced, one of them is solving the equation of motion in certain papers and producing some plots. In case to make it simple here it is

considering the figure. 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.10099  must be the plot which we obtained once we solved eq. 3.1 and 3.2

How do we get the solution of $\phi$ in 3.1, where it has $h$ in it.  While in another case, if we try to solve $h$ in 3.2, it has $\phi$ in it. I have been trying to solve those EOM using WKB approximation and approximate them in small field limit to simplify them. In my case I found

$$ \phi  \propto \frac{e^{i\int \Omega_k t}}{\sqrt(2 \Omega_k)} $$

However, I have no idea, what kind of the exact solution to produce such a plot in the figure. 2.

Please give me a hint or two,

Answer (score 0):

seems I missed using a numerical technique in this case, and finally, the problem is solved. It has shown a 'really' similar plot. One can really use the runge-kutta method in phyton.

It is shown the 'quite' really different compared by the analytic ones.